# Facebook button JavaScript code loads twice

Tags: javascript

I added the code of the 'Facebook share button' to my site. 
here is the code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="box_count"></div>
```

and here is the test page : http://www.2knowmyself.com/Privacy_policy

I noticed that the footer of the page loads, then loads again after being displaced (maybe it's not double loading - not sure what that is).

When I removed the Facebook code the page worked properly.

To best replicate the issue, load the page then scroll down to the footer asap to see what happens there while the page is loading. What can I do to fix that problem?

Comment: Hi Mohamed. We try to encourage people to ask "self-contained" questions here, since links to sites are not very useful to future readers who may wish to learn from your problem. I expect you will fix the problem in a day or two, and at that point people following the link will not understand what the problem was. Can you add the relevant items of code to your question, and perhaps prepare a JS Fiddle?

Comment: hi, i will remove the link when its fixed don't worry
i am not a programmer so i dont really know what else to post